# How to always open in Responsive Design Mode?

Tags: firefox, web, firefox-developer-tools

How to make Mozila Firefox always open Youtube site in Responsive Design Mode?
So that i don't have to always press Ctrl+Shift+M.

Comment: What's the intention behind your question? Why would you always want to open a specific website in RDM?

Comment: I just like it more than the web view and i thought there was maybe a setting to make it always open in RDM.

Answer (score 1):

There is unfortunately no such option because the Responsive Design Mode is really just meant to be used for debugging a website.

If it's enough for you to have the viewport size like on a mobile device, you can simply resize the browser window accordingly, though that affects all websites, of course, not just one specific site.